# String widens to Integer, With out InvalidCastException

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

**Case I:**

```
var xTest = "Hello world";  //String variable.
xTest += 10; //Integer widens to String.

alert(xTest);
```

*Result : Hello world10*

**Case II:**

```
var xTest = 10; //Integer variable.
xTest += "Hello World"; //String widens to integer.

alert(xTest);
```

*Result : 10Hello world*

Case I and Case II are performing in a same way. `Integer` widens to `string`, it is acceptable.
But how does a `String` widens to `integer` and how can it return a `string`.? It should have 
thrown a `InvalidCastException`. Am i right.? and Can we convert the `Type` of a `variable` at any point.?
[say, we are using a `variable` 'x' inside the `script` for our doing calculations (Ex: x = 10 * 5), later on
meaning after 5 lines of `code` can we use the same `integer variable` for `String manipulations`.?]
I am little bit confused at this moment.

I am learning `JS` [Migrating from `VB.Net`]

Comment: Javascript [`parseInt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: This is'nt C, there is no casting. Everytime you try to join an integer and a string, it ends up string, as integers only supports numbers, strings can to some degree be parsed to integers with parseFloat and parseInt.

Comment: @adeneo, Oh fine thanks, But here how can i decide one variable's type whether it is integer or string.? by using how it was declared initially.?

Comment: Just forget everything you know about setting variables to certain types, declaring them at the top etc. as you don't need it. JS figures this out and does automatic conversion and hoisting.

Comment: Here's something to help you; https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

Answer (score 0):

There is no int datatype in JavaScript. There is Number which inherits from Object, which in turn has a toString() method which will be used in both of your examples to concat the two objects to a new object. You can read more about the Number object at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp